# Can vanilla multi armed bandit problems be solved by RL algorithms like A2C and PPO?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, advantage-actor-critic

Let's say we have N bandit machines with some distributions (assume some are gaussian, some are uniform, some are chi squared). We want to maximize rewards in X amount of time. I am aware that algorithms like Epsilon greedy, UCB can handle this. But is applying an RL algorithm like A2C the right choice to a plain vanilla Multi Armed Bandit problem (N independent machines that we have to maximize rewards from in X amount of time)? Is the notion even correct? Given that there is only always one state.